# C++ Convert char array to string array

Tags: c++

I have next C++ code in VS2019 under Windows 10:

```
char const* const fileName = "random_StringArray_10000000";

FILE* infile;
long fileSize;
char* buffer;
size_t readBytes;        

infile = fopen(fileName, "rb");
if (infile == NULL)
{
    fputs("File error", stderr); exit(1);
}

fseek(infile, 0, SEEK_END);
fileSize = ftell(infile);
rewind(infile);

buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * fileSize);
if (buffer == NULL)
{
    fputs("Memory error", stderr); exit(2);
}


auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();

readBytes = fread(buffer, 1, fileSize, infile);   

auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();

if (readBytes != fileSize)
{
    fputs("Reading error", stderr); exit(3);
}

fclose(infile);
free(buffer);

auto elapsed_ms = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);

cout << "Elapsed ms: " << elapsed_ms.count() << endl;
cout << "String count: " << stringCount << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
```

This method used because it is fastest way to read file from disk under VS2019.
Now i need to convert char array to the string array.
random_StringArray_10000000 - UTF8 text file.
Strings lenght 8 - 120 symbols.
Hex view of this file:
[image]

0x0D 0x0A separate strings.

Which fastest way to convert char array (buffer) to the C++ string array?

Comment: Define 'string array' in greater detail. That phrase could mean multiple things.

Comment: The fastest way would probably be to create an array of pointers to your existing char array.

Comment: using `std::fstream` and `std::getline` would do all this in a couple of lines of code rather than using c functions.

Comment: You sound like you want to split a string on newline characters. `it is fastest way to read file` Are you sure? Have you measured it?

Comment: @KamilCuk yes am sure about it. I run difficult configuration tests (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1246550/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-vs2019-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%a1-%d0%a1?noredirect=1#comment2190622_1246550)  and on this way is the fastest for me

Comment: @Deim -- What's the reason for mentioning how you're reading in the data?  I see no relevance.  The question you're really asking as that given a string delimited by carriage return / line feed, how to split the string.

Comment: @john i mean array of strings which contain all strings from this file as separate array elements.

Comment: If reading the file content is critical in terms of performance, then [`mmap()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) or [file mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/file-mapping) should probably be considered.

Comment: @Deim C strings or C++ strings? Like I said your phrase has multiple possible meanings. It usually better to write code than try to describe code.

Comment: @john question fixed. C++ strings

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a regularity to your data, all strings are eight characters long and separated by the same two characters. With that in mind the following seems fairly fast.

```
size_t arraySize = readBytes/10;
std::string* array = new std::string[arraySize];
for (size_t i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i)
    array[i].assign(buffer + 10*i, 8);
```

Of course timing is necessary to be sure what is fastest.

Answer (score 3):

Reading lines of text from a file is much simpler if you use the classes from the c++ standard library.

This should be all of the code you need:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char const* const fileName = "random_StringArray_10000000";
    std::ifstream in(fileName);
    if (!in)
    {
        std::cout << "File error\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::vector<std::string> lines;
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(in, line))
    {
        lines.push_back(std::move(line));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: getline give me in debug mode only 2-4 Mb/sec and 10 Mb/sec in Release -O2. fread  - 240 Mb/sec in debug mode and up to 355 Mb/sec in Release mode

Comment: benchmarking in debug is meaningless, how big is your file? is it really that critical to read it faster? In a lot of cases its better to write simple, correct code than prematurely optimise into something complex with hidden bugs

Comment: Up to 50Gb. I planed to read big files by parts (~100Mb each part)

Answer (score 0):

`char as[ ] = "a char array";` : is a char array

`char const* const fileName = "random_StringArray_10000000";`  : is a c string

This is also a c string:

`char* cs = const_cast<char*>( fileName );`

If you want `std::string` use:

`std::string s(as);`

I wasn't sure which string conversion you wanted so I just added what I could off the top of my head. But here's a compilable [example](https://onlinegdb.com/_Yp6-Erwi) too.